# Postgresql odbc driver error c# [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found

Tags: c#, database, odbc, postgresql-9.5

I am setting up an database application to be database agnostic, and when testing with postgresql I get the standard dsn error:

> [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found

I usually use SQL server and MySQL so I'm new to postgres, I tried the standard recommended Connection string:

```
"Driver = {PostgreSQL}; Server = localhost; Database = postgres; Port = 5432; Uid = postgres; Pwd = XXXXXX;"
```

I also tried the name of the odbc driver that I installed after installing postrgesql:

```
"Driver = {PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)}; Server = localhost; Database = postgres; Port = 5432; Uid = postgres; Pwd = XXXXXX;"
```

Setting up a DSN in odbc manager also works perfectly using the unicode driver, so I cant understand why i cant connect in my application, is there an error in the driver name that i am using in the connection string?

Answer (score 1):

Your error message looks very strange. It tells about DSN not found. Are you sure you use connect string with `Driver=...`?

You can use ODBC connect string in several forms. At first you have created DSN, so you can use it:

```
DSN=mn_test; Uid=postgres; Pwd=postgres;
```

Then you can use other form of connect string:

```
Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};Server=127.0.0.1; Port=5493; Database=mn_test; Uid=postgres; Pwd=postgres;
```

Both work on my old 32 bit Windows environment. I test them with simple Python script (I use ActiveState Python in which there is simple `odbc` module):

```
import odbc

def test_odbc(connect_string):
    print(connect_string)
    db = odbc.odbc(connect_string)
    c = db.cursor()
    rs = c.execute("SELECT version()")
    for txt in c.fetchall():
        print('%s' % (txt[0]))
    print('-----')

test_odbc('Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE};Server=127.0.0.1; Port=5493; Database=mn_test; Uid=postgres; Pwd=postgres;')
test_odbc('DSN=mn_test; Uid=postgres; Pwd=postgres;')
```

Comment: Its working now, after a restart and I copied the Driver name letter for letter from the registry, I was using the suffix (x64) as suggested on some other websites for the driver name, but actually this is not required on the standard odbc driver installed that comes with the postgresql package, and was probably what caused my problem, also only referencing the driver as {PostgreSQL} also does not work with the standard ODBC driver.

Answer (score 1):

When you created the DSN, did you create it with the correct odbcad tool? With the 64bit version found in `C:\Windows\System32` if your application is 64bit and with the 32bit version found in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` if your application is 32bit?